# How to remove keyboard shortcut for app?

Tags: macos, keyboard, google-chrome, shortcut

Specifically, I am used to typing <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd> in a WordPress admin area to specify some text as a Header 1, (and <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>2</kbd> to specify Header 2), but when I do this now in Chrome, that command seems to change the current browser tab.

Is there a way to edit or remove the chrome keyboard commands so those commands will work with WordPress, (I am assuming that the Chrome commands over-ride the WordPress admin ones)?

Using an iMac running OS X Yosemite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a OS X problem. It's a Chrome problem.

When a browser receives a keystroke, it needs to decide whether to apply it to the webpage first or its UI/chrome(lower-case). Google Chrome chose the latter as a design decision. Firefox made the opposite choice. As a consequence, when a Firefox user tries to COMMAND+ARROW to go back/forward, he might end up flipping through slideshows on that page.

There is nothing you can do on the OS end as everything passes through browser. You can use an addon to disable specific native browser shortcuts. I know how with Firefox, not Chrome. Or you can modify the javascript embedded in wordpress site, and come up with new non-conflicting shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

I've used https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/ before, but I'm not sure if it will allow you to use it the way you've described. Perhaps reading their docs for re-mapping keys.

Comment: Thanks.  I did not know about this.  I tried to up vote this response but I do not have the ability with my new account.